# Partial reverse url lookup in django

Tags: python, django

I'm looking for a way to efficiently do reverse url lookup on a large number of django model instances, ideally without needing to call `reverse()` once for each instance.  My original code looked something like this:

```
urls = []
for foo in Foo.objects.all():
    url = django.core.urlresolvers.reverse("foo_details", kwargs={"ver": foo.version,
                                                                  "locale": foo.locale,
                                                                  "name": foo.name})
    urls.append(url)
```

However, since there are a large number (thousands) of Foo objects, this process took far too long. So, I faked a "partial" url lookup once, then completed the job for each instance:

```
base_url = django.core.urlresolvers.reverse("foo_details", kwargs={"ver": foo.version,
                                                                   "locale": foo.locale,
                                                                   "name": ""})
urls = []
for foo in Foo.objects.all():
    url = base_url + urlquote(foo.name)
    urls.append(url)
```

This works, and it is much faster than my first solution, but I'm now making assumptions about the form of the url, specifically that name will always appear at the very end. Also, I'd like to make use of `get_absolute_url()` for this, but that eliminates the possibility of doing a partial reversal of the url only once, then completing the reversal for each object.

Is this really the only way? Is there some other way that I could keep the partial reverse lookup, then complete the url for each individual object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I usually do something along the lines of

```
placeholder = "__placeholder___"
base = reverse("foo_details", 
               kwargs={"ver": foo.version,
                       "locale": foo.locale,
                       "name": placeholder})
# ...
url = base.replace(placeholder, foo.name)
```

which works around the assumption that the name is the last path component.

Comment: Yes, I had considered this approach, and I think it will likely be what I do in the end.  Two things made me hesitant to do this in the first place.  First, I don't see a way to make this work with `get_absolute_url()`, but I suppose that is unavoidable.  The second is that I have very few restrictions on what `foo.name` can be. For example, I have no way of knowing that `"__placeholder__"` is not the value of `foo.name`.  However, now that I think about it, that probably isn't a major issue, given that replacing `"__placeholder__"` with `"__placeholder__"` should work just fine.

Comment: You could always try to make the placeholder something that cannot occur in a URL (spaces, %% or whatnot). No idea if reverse() sanitises its return value though.

Comment: Unfortunately (for this case) it does.

Comment: I like this solution better than defining a "sister" url that doesn't have the parameter and concatenating strings; this method seems less "hacky".